# How to connect to proxy server using Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I want to write a java(SE) program to connect to a proxy server, lets say 123.123.123.123:8080. How am I going to achieve that? What is the protocol between my machine and the proxy server? What is the Java framework's class could be in use?

Comment: What kind of a proxy server? Socks? HTTP?

Answer (score 4):

since java 1.5,you can use java.net.Proxy class to create proxy.

```
Proxy proxy=new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("123.123.123.123", 8080);
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");
HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);
uc.connect();
```

[reference](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0085.html)

Comment: From the example above, is the connection between my pc and the proxy server a kind of http protocol?

Comment: you can change proxy type by `Proxy.Type.HTTP` or `Proxy.Type.SOCKS`

Answer (score 1):

The definitive reference for network proxy configuration in Java 5 is this [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/proxies.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes proxy server is a web server...
Whenever u send a request through your browser to get some resource in the particular web server(say www.google.com),the request is send to the proxy server instead to sending the request directly to the google server..the proxy server process this request,send them to the gooogle server,receives the response and then send the response back to the browser.
Proxy server is basically used to corporate fields to restrict the accesss to specific websites,to keep a track of the internet used by a particular associate,Also it saves some commoonly used webpages in a cache file,so that when another request comes,then instead of connecting to the required server,it get the webpage fron the cache file..Hence it saves the time.Also it scans the incoming data from any server for malware before submitting it to the client(browser).To check if ur company is using proxy server,u can go to the internet explorer setting ->Connections ->LAN Settings